# how to press Print Screen button on document ready automatically? Without the actually any user press the button

Tags: jquery

I want to press the print screen button on document ready using jQuery.
I don't want that user press the button. I just want that if there is a chance to click the prtScr button to take a screenshot for a purpose.

Comment: you could use window.print();

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that using jQuery,

To put it simply, jQuery belongs to the document domain, you can do things limited to the document.

Your browser has a larger domain, and then, there is the desktop/OS domain, the Keyboard key press and the the Print Screen feature live here, far away from your document.

However, you might want to look into using the "[Screen Capture API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Capture_API/Using_Screen_Capture)" It can let you capture the screen content using the browser scpope though Web APIs